# Pointer to Array char overlaps

Tags: c

Question, I am stuck on getting these arrays print correctly. The aim is to select an item from the first index choosing a number. So when I choose 1, All the Swords are listed and when I choose 2, all the Shields are shown etc.

```
char readarray(char **_array){
    for (int i=1;_array[i]!='\0';i++) {
        printf("%d - %s\n",i, _array[i]);
    }
    return **_array;
}

int main(){

char *index[25]={"N/A","Swords","Shields", "Helmets not yet created", "Boots not yet created"};
char *Swords[25]={"N/A","Rapier","Dual Blade","Katana"};
char *Shields[25]={"N/A","Tower Shield","Wooden Shield","Golden Shield"};
int choice;

printf("Welcome\n");
printf("_________________\n");

printf("Please make a choice\n");

readarray(index);//Lists first index of Items
choice=(getch()-'0');//Asks to make a choice

for (int i=1;i<choice;i++)
    {if (strcmp(index[i],"Swords")==0)
        {readarray(Swords);}
    else if (strcmp(index[i],"Shields")==0)
        {readarray(Shields);}
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What happens here is that when I choose 2, The index Swords is printed out correctly as a list. However when I choose 3 or higher, the array Swords is still printed before Shields, while I am asking only to print out the Array Shields in this case. Any ideas what I do wrong?

Comment: Please fix the code formatting. You have a ton of HTML codes in there for some reason, preventing simply fixing the indentation to have proper code highlighting

Comment: Did you read the compiler warnings? Which ones do you get? They seem pretty clear.... telling you what is strange about e.g. `_array[i]!='\0'`.

Comment: "I am asking only to print out the Array Shields in this case. " Really? I see a loop starting at 1 going through to below `choice`. What exactly surprises you?

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the compiler warnings, with an input of 1, I get an output of

```
Welcome
_________________
Please make a choice
1 - Swords
2 - Shields
3 - Helmets not yet created
4 - Boots not yet created
```

This is because the loop is not executed at all.
The list output is from `readarray(index);`.

With a choice of 2, I get an output of

```
Welcome
_________________
Please make a choice
1 - Swords
2 - Shields
3 - Helmets not yet created
4 - Boots not yet created
1 - Rapier
2 - Dual Blade
3 - Katana
```

I.e. same as before, pluse the first iteration of the loop, starting at 1, while `i` is smaller than `choice`, i.e. exactly one iteration for "1", with the output from `readarray(Swords);`.

With a choice of "3", I get same as before, plus the second iteration of the loop, with the additional output for `i` being 2 (being smaller than 3), from `readarray(Shields);`.

Nothing about that surprises me, apart from the fact that you seem to expect something different from that code.

If you want only one output, for the list which matches `choice`you probably want no loop and compare directly via `choice`:

```
//for (int i=1;i<choice;i++)
    if (strcmp(index[choice],"Swords")==0)
        {readarray(Swords);}
    else if (strcmp(index[choice],"Shields")==0)
        {readarray(Shields);}
    else
        { /* output "Not implemented." or "Can't find." */ }
```

Which gets you output of the chosen list, if implemented; otherwise no output.

Comment: Actually I tink you want an array of arrays, from which to pick directly via using `choice` as index, but that would be changing too much of your code choices...